# R: Select ALL values in subset / select function

Tags: r, select

I am trying to create an interactive function where multiple values can be selected from a list, passed to a function which selects on the basis of information supplied. Using

```
subset(..., select(..., subset(...)))
```

works very well for election of specific values, and simply putting a '#' in front of one of the selection rows allows me to extract all values. The pre-function version of the code is below

I want to supply the parameters in the form

```
Service = c("SMS", "Data", ...), Country = c("Cyprus", "Egypt")
```

for each of the selections, and I want to be able to select all values for those parameters where no selection is made. This would be easy in SQL, with

```
SELECT *
```

but I can't find any equivalent term in the R Select() function.

```
# Selection
dashselect <- subset(DashboardSource, select=c(Date, Currency,Direction,Partner,
                                                   Agreement, Country, Service,     Amount..USD.,
                                           Minutes, Mb, SMS, DbSMonth, DbSYear),
                 subset=c(
                           (Direction == "Outbound"  ) &
#                               (Country=="Portugal" | Country=="Egypt") &
                           (Service =="SMS" | Service == "Data") &
#                               (Date >= "2013/1/1" & Date <= "2015/01/01" ) &
#                               (Partner =="") &
#                               (Agreement == "")  
#                               (Minutes > "")
                           (Mb >1000) &
#                               (Amount..USD. > "") 
                          (SMS >= 0)
                          )
                )
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Don't use `subset`. Use `[`.

Comment: +1 for selection through `[]`. It would be great if you attached some reproducable data example to your question. It would make easier helping you get the results you want.

Comment: If you are selecting from a dataframe (which by your use of `subset`, it appears that you are), then you can use the `sqldf` package and access `SELECT *` type functionality directly. The powerhouse function of the `sqldf` package is `sqldf()` which will take a sqlite-compliant statement using dataframes as "tables". You could, in conjunction with `paste()`, use `sqldf()` to build a function that would probably meet your needs. As stated, some reproducible data would allow me to demonstrate this in an actual answer.

Comment: I find subset=c(...) and select=c(...) much more readable than [] and [[ ]], it is very easy to get lost in forests of parentheses and readability is certainly improved.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your input arguments, do something like:

```r
selDate <- DashboadSource$Date %in% select$Date# Logical index will be all FALSE if select$Date is NULL (i.e. no argument provided)
if(all( selDate == FALSE)){ selProj <- selProj == FALSE}# If all FALSE, change to all TRUE
```

Now query your dataframe with:

```r
dashSelect <- DashboadSource[selDate & selCurrency & ... & selDbSYear, ]
```

**Edit:**
As an improvemed implementation, you can first define this function:

```r
nullProof <- function(selIn){
if(all(selIn == F)){selOut <- selIn == F}
else{selOut <- selIn}
return(selOut) }
```

Then use the function on each of your input arguments in turn:

```r
selDate     <- nullProof(DashboadSource$Date %in% select$Date)
selCurrency <- nullProof(DashboadSource$Currency %in% select$Currency)
#etc.
```

Then query your dataframe as above.

Comment: As a beginner in R, I refrain from an elaborate answer including reproducible data, but I'll gladly share my workaround because I'm surprised a seemingly common problem like this has no answer.